# Фризы вращающегося спрайта в пустом проекте Unity

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, 2d

При разработке игры столкнулся с проблемой.
Вращающийся спрайт периодически притормаживает. Этот баг я смог воспроизвести даже в пустом проекте. В проекте есть лишь 1 скрипт и спрайт:

вращаю этим способом
transform.Rotate(rotationSpeedVector * Time.deltaTime);

В проекте создан один пустой объект на который я вешаю скрипт вращения. В пустой объект помещаю спрайт и смещаю его от центра.

После запуска профайлер показывает такую картину

[image: profiler]
На платформах Android и Windows этот фриз почти не виден, но он есть если следить взглядом за спрайтом. Однако на IOS этот фриз становится очень сильно заметен и мешает играть. Пожалуйста подскажите как можно это исправить.
Баг воспроизводится на нескольких пк, версии юнити 5.4.0 5.5.1 5.6.0
Проект: https://bitbucket.org/small_games/rotate

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Answer (score 0):

1. Вращать нужно в Update, а не в LateUpdate, если нужна плавность.
2. Application.targetFrameRate используется неверно - рывки получаются в том числе и из-за этой ошибки. На iOS по умолчанию ставится 30fps (если из кода не было выставлено иное значение), для унификации можно делать установку одинакового числа на всех платформах из кода.
3. Для замедления / ускорения следует использовать [Time.timeScale](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html) - при одинаковой частоте кадров будет меняться Time.deltaTime и анимация будет происходить с меньшим или большим шагом.

Comment: Подскажите, как именно нужно было использовать Application.targetFrameRate и в чем моя ошибка?

Comment: В комментарии уже было описано, как правильно использовать - поставить на 30 или 60 и не трогать в принципе. Менять следует Time.timeScale.